# "I took my dog to the vet." - acceptable when I have more than one dog?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have two dogs, and one was sick so I took him to the vet.
Should I say (1) or (2) when I tell this to the listener?

Is (1) correct?

> (1) I took my dog to the vet.
>
> (2) I took one of my dogs to the vet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.

The first sentence doesn't tell the listener how many dogs you have; but the second sentence tells him that you've more than one dog.

So you can say either of these sentences.

If you want to say that you have two dogs, you could say:

*"I took one of my **two** dogs to the vet."*

Answer (score 1):

Both are completely fine.

The second contains extra information (that you have more than one dog). The first sentence is correct, it just doesn't have that information.

Which one you use would depend only on whether "I have more than dog" is relevant to your situation.